# How to pass php code in this in label_htm i want to show count number in this filed

Tags: javascript, php

```
"My tasks" => array(
        "title" => "My tasks",
        "label_htm" => '<span class="badge pull-right inbox-badge margin-right-13">2</span>',
        "icon" => "fa-slack",

        'url' => APP_URL.'/my_task.php'
        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Just instead `2` value, concat this string with PHP variable, i.e.:

```
'<span class="badge pull-right inbox-badge margin-right-13">' . $count . '</span>'
```

Comment: please explain what you want. Do you need to use ajax?

Comment: @JigneshBrandYou If you find my answer helpful, remember to mark it with the tick on the left.

Answer (score 0):

```
$count_num = 2; 

    "My tasks" => array(
            "title" => "My tasks",
            "label_htm" => '<span class="badge pull-right inbox-badge margin-right-13">'.$count_num.'</span>',
            "icon" => "fa-slack",

            'url' => APP_URL.'/my_task.php'
            ),
```